# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: python 3.9.1

Tags: python

I am creating a code for a hotel booking system and it is coming up with the error message

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

This error message shows up every time i run it and nothing else I have tried has worked

```
#this program is a hotel booking system
#this program was created on 18/01/21

def Display_heading_and_set_up_variables():
    global Hotel_Name, Price_Per_Night
    print("HOTEL BOOKING SYSTEM")
    Hotel_Name = str("Hotel_indigo")
    Price_Per_Night = float("69.99")

def Get_Number_Of_Nights():
    global No_Of_Nights, answer, confirmation
    #this part of the program will get the number of nights the person is staying for 
    answer = False
    while answer == False: 
            No_Of_Nights = input(int("How many nights are you going to stay for:"))
            while No_Of_Nights  <= 1  >= 21:
                print("That is an invalid entry - nights booked must be from 1 to 21")
                No_Of_Nights = input(int("How many nights are you going to stay for:"))
            confirmation = input(str("Have you chosen the correct number of nights you want to stay for:"))
            if confirmation == Y or confirmation == y:
                answer = True

def Discount_Calculator():
    global No_Of_Nights, Discount_percentage
    #this part of the program will work out the discount from the number of nights you stayed for
    if No_Of_Nights == 1  ==2:
        Discount_percentage = 0
    elif No_Of_Nights >= 3 <= 7:
        Discount_percentage = 5
    elif No_Of_Nights >= 8 <= 14:
        Discount_percentage = 10
    elif No_Of_Nights >= 15 <= 21:
        Discount_percentage = 15

def calculate_and_display_final_booking_details():
    #this part of the program will calculate and display your final information on booking
    global No_Of_Nights, Discount_percentage, Hotel_Name, Price_Per_Night, Discounted_Price_Per_Night
    Discounted_Price_Per_Night = Price_Per_Night / 100 * Discount_percentage + Price_Per_Night
    print("you have booked" ,No_Of_Nights, "number of nights")
    print("you qualify for a" ,Discount_Percentage, "% discount")
    print(" the final cost of your booking is:" ,Discounted_Price_Per_Night,)
#main program
Display_heading_and_set_up_variables()
Get_Number_Of_Nights()
calculate_and_display_final_booking_details()
```

How do I fix this? Thanks In advance

Comment: Exceptions come from Python, not the IDE, such as IDLE.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong

```
input(int("how many nights are you going to stay for:")
```

Try

`int(input("how many nights are you going to stay for:"))`

Same for other lines, u are trying to convert a string to int, which is wrong

Comment: thanks for the help but now it is saying that the y and Y are not defined

Comment: Put the y or Y in quotes "", These are simple errors, start googling

Comment: If this is the OP's problem, the question should be closed as caused by a typo, not answered. See the *Answer Well-Asked Questions* section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: ...and if the question is so ill-specified as to not have _just one specific problem it's about_, it should be closed as too broad.